# Unable to Serialize item, but running admin serialization works fine

Tags: serialization

We're running Sitecore 8.1 Update-3 (160519) and are running into issues with serialization.

Using the standard admin account, if we select an item, for example **/sitecore/content/home** and run "Serialize item" in the Developer tab there's no message in the Sitecore Desktop, no browser console errors (Chrome or IE, see **Edit 1**), and no messages of any sort in the standard Sitecore logs.

Sadly, no serialization directory is created, and if one exists, it is not populated with any files.

If we visit https://example.com/sitecore/admin/serialization.aspx and run the serialization process, however, the serialization directory is properly populated.

We've checked permissions and the user account associated with the site does have the appropriate rights to the entire data directory, and can obviously populate it if we use the admin page.

After the admin serialization took place we also tried renaming the **master** directory in the serialization folder and running Serialize item on an individual item again, to no avail.

Is there a reason serializing an individual item might not work? What would be the recommended next steps to determine why the Serialize item command isn't working?

### Edit 1

There are three console errors in Chrome, all with the same text:

> X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside .

These are on the following items, after starting up the Content Editor in Sitecore Desktop. They've been going on for a while, and don't seem to have an impact on using the content editor.

- EditorWindow.aspx:4
- Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingFieldDetails.aspx?db=master&id={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C…:39
- Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.SecurityDetails.aspx?db=master&id={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5…:41

This appears to be [a known issue](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/3810) so I don't typically count these.

### Edit 2

After digging into the code, and posting to a Sitecore Slack channel, it appears there may be [a bug in Unicorn where serialization is not passed back to Sitecore](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/issues/219). Per the documentation it should be. Issue created and will update as I find out more.

Comment: Check your console. Are you getting any JavaScript errors that might be preventing it from serializing.

Comment: Technically we're getting the 'standard' Sitecore 8.1 errors regarding X-Frame-Options, which I've added into the question, but otherwise no, as noted above no errors when using the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point this appears to be from a bug in Unicorn 3.3.2.

Upgrading to Unicorn 4.0 prerelease 9 resolved the issue.

See https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/issues/219 for more information.